# Exception Strings for Mobile Devices not working in magento

Tags: android, ios, ipad, magento, mobile

I have read on [Disable a Magento mobile theme for tablet & iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741131/disable-a-magento-mobile-theme-for-tablet-ipad/25300031#25300031) how to change the ipad from using the mobile theme to the default desktop theme.

I have used:

```
iPhone|iPod|Mobile - with 'value' iPhone|Mobile
```

with

```
iPad|Tablet - with value default
```

Unfortunately it hasn't worked for me. In one of the answers to that post ANKIT recommended applying a user agent widths. I tried doing the below but it hasn't worked.

```
iPad|Tablet ((?!(1024|768)).)
```

can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I solved by adding two exceptions in System > Configuration > Design:

try to add an exception that states:

Matched Expression:
iPad|Tablet

Value
your_default_theme

Then add another exception that states:

Matched Expression:
iPhone|iPod|Mobile|mobile

Value
your_mobile_theme